# JavaFX WebVIew - PDF on popup window

Tags: pdf, javafx, oracle-adf

I have posted some other smaller questions regarding the problem I describe below and got some feedback but now I will try to explain it in more depth hoping to get through the problem.

I built a desktop application using JavaFX 2.2 which uses a WebEngine to access a website built using Oracle ADF Pages. The application tracks the users actions on the pages and stores data to a database. All fine so far until the point where I need show a PDF file on a user click.

On the actual website the user clicks a button and a new popup window opens up that displays the PDF.

My problem is that due to the lack of PDF support in JavaFX I cannot display the pdf. The actual link to the PDF is dynamic and it doesn't have a .pdf at the end of it so I can't use the actual URL to send it to an external bowser or something to display it. Additionally the connection is secure so I can't open the URL with Chrome for example.

Possible solutions I thought about are to read the binary data of the response from WebView and create the PDF file locally and then open it using Adobe of Chrome or something. Is that possible at all? 
Another solution I thought about (while I am writing this question) is maybe to open the URL which the users default browser but how can I go about sending the secure connection cookie from the application to the browser.

Is any of the above even possible? Am I missing something?

Any help, clues, links, ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do what you want is to download the PDF and display it locally.

Downloading using WebView sounds like it could work but I'm not familiar with the user experience.  As an alternative try using curl or wget.  You can pass in the authorization cookie to those tools and use them to download the file